# Assertion error from OpenCV checkVector in Python

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, affinetransform

OpenCV uses Numpy arrays as inputs in Python. This abstracts many characteristics of the underlying C++ array.

Next to all functions in OpenCV (e.g. cv2.getAffineTransform) perform checks on the input data in C++ like:

```
inputMat.checkVector(3, CV_32F) == 3
```

The resulting assertion errors are often cryptic and sometimes not properly caught in Python:

```
(-215:Assertion failed) src.checkVector(2, 5) == 3 && dst.checkVector(2, 5) == 3 in function 'cv::getAffineTransform'
```

What exactly can cause these errors and how to interpret them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm going to answer my own question now, as I wasted about three hours of googling to find an answer for this on StackOverflow.

The function [cv::Mat::checkVector()](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a167a8e0a3a3d86e84b70e33483af4466) checks three things:

1. The number of columns in the array as specified by the first argument.
2. The data type specified by the enum in the second argument. When seeing the error in Python the enum value is already parsed (e.g. 5 for CV_32F aka float32). The possible values are:

   `CV_8U   0
   CV_8S   1
   CV_16U  2
   CV_16S  3
   CV_32S  4
   CV_32F  5
   CV_64F  6
   CV_USRTYPE1 7`
   [Source](https://codeyarns.com/2015/08/27/depth-and-type-of-matrix-in-opencv/)
3. The third and less obvious is the check if the input is contiguous. This is specified by a third parameter, which defaults to true. Therefore this error is not directly visible from the assertion error in Python.

To check your numpy arrays for contiguous layout, you can have a look at the `np.ndarray.flags` parameter. Numpy arrays are normally created C-contiguous, but can become non-contiguous through operations like slicing:

```
>> x = np.zeros((10, 68, 3))
>> x.flags
  C_CONTIGUOUS : True
  F_CONTIGUOUS : False
  OWNDATA : True
  WRITEABLE : True
  ALIGNED : True
  WRITEBACKIFCOPY : False
  UPDATEIFCOPY : False
>> x[:, [33, 36, 45]].flags
  C_CONTIGUOUS : False
  F_CONTIGUOUS : False
  OWNDATA : False
  WRITEABLE : True
  ALIGNED : True
```

The np.ndarray.copy() function can make a sliced array contiguous again by giving it the parameter `order='C'`.

Comment: THANK YOU, that contiguous thing was my saving grace. Hate that you can't see it in the error message!